# Analog meter in iOS

Tags: ios, meter

Hi I want to make a analog meter similar to this.
[image]
I found an example "[Guage.java](http://atstechlab.wordpress.com/2010/07/30/gauge-and-dial-widget-for-android/)" but its for Android, do we have something similar to this for iOS

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no component like that for iOS, you'll have to do it yourself or find a 3rd party library that does it.